# How to statically enforce frozen data classes in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to write an example where I'd like to use a frozen dataclass instance during type checking and swap it out with a normal dataclass to avoid paying the instantiation cost of frozen dataclasses.

The goal is to ensure that the instance is immutable with the type checker and use a regular dataclass during runtime. Here's the snippet:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from functools import partial

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    frozen = partial(dataclass, frozen=True)
else:
    frozen = dataclass

@frozen
class Foo:
    x: int
    y: int

foo = Foo(1, 2) # mypy complains about the number of arguments

foo.x = 3 # instead, mypy should complain here
```

This works as expected during runtime, but running mypy raises this error. Pyright gives me the same error as well:

```
foo.py:49: error: Too many arguments for "Foo"  [call-arg]
```

In this snippet, the type checker can catch the mutation error:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    x: int
    y: int

foo = Foo(1, 2)

foo.x = 3 # mypy correctly catches the error here
```

So, I'm guessing that the type checker doesn't like when I'm aliasing `frozen = dataclass` or `frozen = partial(...)`. How do I annotate this properly so that the type checker understands that it's a dataclass instance and doesn't complain about mismatched argument count?

*P.S: This is just an exercise. I know turning on `dataclass(frozen=True)` is way easier, and I shouldn't care about performance in such cases. I was inspired to try this after reading a [blog](https://threeofwands.com/attra-iv-zero-overhead-frozen-attrs-classes/) post by Tin Tvrtković on making attr class instances frozen at compile time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`@dataclass_transform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.dataclass_transform) with `frozen_default = True`:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    T = TypeVar('T')
    
    @dataclass_transform(frozen_default = True)
    def frozen(cls: type[T]) -> type[T]:
        ...
else:
    frozen = dataclass
```

`frozen_default` was added in Python 3.12. However, since `@dataclass_transform` [deliberately accepts all keyword arguments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/#dataclass-transform-parameters), [3.11](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=c2cf678296f6280b19105250813011e4) (exactly the same) and [lower](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=c04091c0ff857e5c485eecd7104b8192) (using `typing_extensions`) will be just fine.

This works with both [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=ee3055f01f892c57b9e87eedc97f1147) and [pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAJghgFzgYwDZwM4YKYagSwgAcwQFZEV0sAoUSKBATyPwDsBzA408gFQCaABQCiAfQDCACRESA0gEkAcgHEANBSRpMGMQhBw2GYKQga%2BLbADU4IGjXzAog0ZJnzlKgFw0of51AAvM6WNiAAFADkfJEAlL7%2BCX4AAvBa1Lr6hsam4fQAXthsYjDYwHAArqjkwXwgFdjx-rBlUAVF4WgYXoyWANp8ALqxUAC0AHy9RNgDgz7NzQB0yzTYqDjz-u1sQZpUOvY0yds02lhQAGJgYJt%2BAB497AhJUEyPbM-2INgAbthwqD0lnCVzAIygAGIoBAWExmoFJuEHgQPho3iiECMJpdri8Fvj-FCiEwQPgOAALGqTZjTPqgwb2ExgXag8IARg0ACZwZDobCoABqKDE0kUqltdjYRnXRZ3XYAZgJfihMOJ8Mm2BA4BAPSE4GmZDhACI7kaWsBJTAUVAjaCzfg8N84DBRmA2KgmHilQsiSSyZSghqtaQehJDGwwOQdGSdhBsBAAEaam2mtqkKbYG12gDcWeu9rw2yAA):

```py
reveal_type(Foo)  # mypy    => (x: int, y: int) -> Foo
                  # pyright => type[Foo]

foo = Foo(1, 2)   # mypy + pyright => fine

foo.x = 3         # mypy    => error: Property "x" defined in "Foo" is read-only
                  # pyright => error: Cannot assign member "x" for type "Foo"; "Foo" is frozen
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!

Here's the mypy playground link:

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=52a0b38b4cb2e67e0859ff6d2900c780